# Dependency Properties

Tags: wpf, dependencies, properties

If I am setting one dependency property equal to another dependency property, will they automatically get updated if one chagnes, or do I still need to bind them. Also if two dp are part of the same object (same type too) and I set them equal to each does the same apply as above, or only this case works and the one above doesn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> will they automatically get updated if one chagnes, or do I still need to bind them

No.  Each is a separate property, and setting one to the other just sets the value.  If you want them to be "bound together" then you should create a binding that binds them together.

This is true whether they're in the same class or different classes.